# Amazon ebs and package installation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm totally new on aws, and I was wondering some questions.

There is what I understood :
Let's imagine I launch a p2.xlarge instance, with ubuntu AMI on it.
I got my instance with ubuntu on it.
Now let's imagine I install some packages, (I want to do deep learning so I need to install a lot of stuff an framework).
Well, but, I want to pause the instance when I don't make computation, to no pay.
If I stop it, will I loose the packages I installed on it since there is no persistant data ? Same thing if I want to add a user to not be a super user all the time..

Last thing : I read about the EBS system, but I can't install all my packages on it right ? If yes, how ? Since it's just a storage place...

Thanks you very much!

Comment: "Since it's just a storage place..." I think you mean EFS, not EBS?

Comment: Well, I read than EBS what just to stock persistant data, no ?
You mount it in your EC2 instance and that's it ?

Comment: EBS is essentially just a hard drive. An instance has a root EBS volume attached, which is where your packages would install. Just like a normal hard drive, turning off the server doesn't wipe out the EBS volume. When you turn it back on, the files are all still there.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, if I create an instance, all is transparent and I have nothing to do with anything to have data persistence ?

Comment: As long as it's not an instance-store-backed instance. AWS has been doing away with these - they're only available at all in the older instance types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about [AMI Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html)

> All AMIs are categorized as either backed by Amazon EBS or backed by
>   instance store. The former means that the root device for an instance
>   launched from the AMI is an Amazon EBS volume created from an Amazon
>   EBS snapshot. The latter means that the root device for an instance
>   launched from the AMI is an instance store volume created from a
>   template stored in Amazon S3.

In short if you use EBS-Backed AMI then your data will persist after stop-start and if you choose the Instance-Backed AMI then you won't be able to stop the instance at all, it can either be running or terminated.

Go with AMI backed AMI's.

Comment: Hi!
So, when I'm on the console, I don't choose an AMI from the store but to create one ?
But to create a snapshot, I need to launch the instance before then mount an ebs, snap it and link it to instance for next time ?
Or it's directly when creating the instance an option ?

Comment: You need not create an ami, you can search for Ubuntu in the store and in the details sectiosn look for **Root Device Type**. It should be ebs.